# Create new customer attribute

Tags: module, magento-1, attributes, customer

I need to create 4 new customer attributes in my magento store. I have created a module as below to do so:

```
Customerattribute >
    etc > config.xml
    Model > Mysql4 > Setup.php
    sql > customerattribute_setup > mysql4-install-0.0.1.php
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Customerattribute>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Custom_Customerattribute>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customerattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_Customerattribute</module>
                    <class>Custom_Customerattribute_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                ....
            </customerattribute_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Setup.php

```
class Custom_Customerattribute_Model_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup 
{
    /**
     * This method returns true if the attribute exists.
     * 
     * @param string|int $entityTypeId
     * @param string|int $attributeId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function attributeExists($entityTypeId, $attributeId) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
            $attributeId = $this->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $attributeId);
            return !empty($attributeId);
        } 
        catch(Exception $e) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entity = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');

if(!$installer->attributeExists($entity, 'paypal')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'paypal');
}

$installer->addAttribute($entity, 'paypal', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Paypal',
        'input' => 'text',
        'visible' => TRUE,
        'required' => FALSE,
        'default_value' => '',
        'adminhtml_only' => '0'
));

$forms = array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'customer_account_edit'
);
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute($installer->getEntityTypeId('customer'), 'paypal');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

This works for my first customer attribute of `paypal` but i now want to be able to add 3 others. I had hoped that if i change the `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php` file to say this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entity = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');

if(!$installer->attributeExists($entity, 'attribute_2')) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2');
}

$installer->addAttribute($entity, 'attribute_2', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Attribute 2',
        'input' => 'text',
        'visible' => TRUE,
        'required' => FALSE,
        'default_value' => '',
        'adminhtml_only' => '0'
));

$forms = array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'customer_account_edit'
);
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute($installer->getEntityTypeId('customer'), 'attribute_2');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

and uploaded the new file and went back onto the site `attribute_2` would be added but it isn't.

Why does this work once but not again?

Answer (score 1):

Install files are only called once. You will have to add your code to a file called `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2` and change the version in your `confix.xml` to `0.0.2`.

Also, what Magento Version are you using? Calling the setup class `Custom_Customerattribute_Model_Mysql4_Setup` and prefixing the install and upgrade files with `mysql4` is deprecated.